# Navigating from a link inside a string in webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I manage to display a webview with the content that being derived from string, there is a link inside the string, www.google.com, webview supposed to make the link browse-able. But in my case, the link just being treated as a normal text, anyone know how to make this link browse-able? Like when clicked it'll open up safari n show the webpage. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will helpful for you.

```
enter code here
```

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

```
NSMutableString *pageStr = [[@"" mutableCopy] autorelease];

[pageStr appendString:@"<head>"];
[pageStr appendString:@"<title>MigraineMate Paint Graph</title>"];
[pageStr appendString:@"</head>"];
[pageStr appendString:@"<body>"];
[pageStr appendString:@"<img src=unknown.png alt=\"Justin Bieber\" style=\"float:left; text-align:left; margin:0px 15px \" width=100  border=1 /> "];

[pageStr appendString:@"<a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com/\">Visit W3Schools</a>  <p>Please Wait   Graph may take a moment to load Please Wait   Graph may take a moment to load   Please Wait   Graph may take a moment to loadPlease Wait   Graph may take a moment to loadPlease Wait   Graph may take a moment to loadPlease Wait   Graph may take a moment to load</p>"];

[pageStr appendString:@"</body>"];
[pageStr appendString:@"</html>"];

[imgWebView  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[imgWebView  setOpaque:NO];
[imgWebView loadHTMLString:pageStr baseURL:baseURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a hyperlink inside of a `UIWebView` you need to use the proper HTML syntax.

```
<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

Unless I misunderstand your question, in which case I would appreciate a clarification.

---

In response to the OP's clarification in a comment on this answer:

You can either parse out the links and generate the HTML before you display the string in the `UIWebView`, or use JavaScript to do the same thing.

Alternatively, you can use a `UITextView` which will automatically enable hyperlinks: simply assign `UIDataDetectorTypeLink` to its `dataDetectorTypes` property.

Comment: No, it's not what I mean, what I mean is, I declare a UIWebView and pass in set of strings as it's content, and inside those strings, there is a weblink, when I see the application running, the webview show the content correctly, but the link that supposed to be link was treated as a normal text, what I want is that the link to be treated as normal link(which can be clicked). Get what I mean?